# Image not displaying at runtime

Tags: wpf, image, xaml

I have a WPF project called Guitar, the guitar.png image did display at visual studio. But whenever I run the project, the image didn't display at runtime. This is killing me.

```
<Image Canvas.Left="640" Canvas.Top="297"  Name="guitar" Source="/Guitar;component/guitar.png" Stretch="None"/>
```

Are there anyone have the same problem before?

Comment: what's with the semicolon in the path?

Comment: @SteveCav That's a Pack Uri.  See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970069.aspx

Comment: Can you check the Build Action is set to Resource for that image in your project?

Answer (score 0):

After set image source to "guitar.png", it works.